Shape of a rectangular strip after Torsion
Within elastic range of deformation what is the shape of the central surface of a thin long rectangular strip twisted by pure torque?
Theory of Elasticity  (Timoshenko/ Goodier) has the formula for twist angle per unit length:
$$ \theta= \frac{M_t}{\dfrac G3 bc^3}= \frac{M_t}{GJ}$$
where ${b,c,M_t}$ are width, thickness of the strip and twisting moment respectively.
Since $\theta$ is constant, does it follow that the twisted shape is a part of a helicoid? Is helicoid (right or left) mentioned in original works of St.Venant, Nadai or Prandtl?
In case of pure bending, the curvature is proportional to bending moment $\kappa= \dfrac{M}{EI}$ per Euler-Bernoulli Law. $(E,I)$ are isotropic elastic moduli, the constant of proportionality is $ EI$. A beam bends to an arc of a circle.
EDIT1:
Analogous relations for bending and torsion are given as:
$$\frac{M}{I}=\frac{E}{R_{curv}}=E\kappa_{Bndg}=\frac{\sigma}{c},\epsilon=c \kappa_{Bndg}~;$$
$$\frac{M_t}{J}=\frac{G}{R{_{trsn}}}=G\tau_{Trsn}=\frac{\tau}{c},\gamma=c \tau_{Trsn}~;$$
but it is not clear how the latter relations are relevant to a helicoid whereas clearly the former relations are relevant to a beam deforming to a circle.
EDIT2:
It appears to me that a Torsion Law, corresponding Euler's Law of principal curvatures, may be valid... when each warped section deforms to a saddle shape could one suppose
$$ \tau_{n}= \tau_{1} \cos^2\psi +\tau_{2} \sin ^2 \psi~ $$
as valid? The saddle is not flat, essentially a non-linear deformation. The warped layers are hyperbolic paraboloids $w= k\cdot xy$ where the constant is evaluated from material properties and ellipse geometry.
To support the research there is evidence of elliptical "section" boundary in rods clearly warping/ deforming to saddle shaped layers. ( Art. 91, Page 263, Fig 149, Timoshenko/Goodier, 1951, McGraw-Hill Co). Result follows from the classical Stress function theory approach  in this textbook. However I could not see torsion stress variation in the form as above for a similar deformation mode form in accessible/ available contemporary continuum mechanics sources.
Also stress (and strain) are depicted similarly on the same Mohr's circle.
Please comment and help to bring treatment of bending and torsion on par in this resarch effort.
